# Overlay chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, overlay

I am in the middle of a Extension build. Basically I'm trying to do a web-based RPG based off of PMOG(the Nethernet). I'm looking for some kind of overlay function like this:
http://img.skitch.com/20080814-ms5hmqh3433rgt7cg2yg13kcka.jpg
Any ideas?

**edit**

Also, is there any way I can log the websites someone goes to, without actually logging the websites? I'm trying to base EXP earned and Gold earned on how many times they go to a website per day. (I.E. 40xp/gold the first time and 10 every other time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create "pop overs", you would create a `<div>` on the page with a very high `z-index` (which is a CSS attribute). `z-index` determine what goes on top of what else. From there, you can use absolute/relative positioning to determine where it should appear on the screen (again, using CSS). To show/dismiss it, you can use a large variety of JavaScript techniques (including sliding it in from off the page).

Comment: I need something that will work internet-wide, something client-sided. I can always use the desktop notifications but those are iffy and they tend to get on users nerves.

Comment: If you can inject JavaScript into the current page, then you can use that to create a new div on the page, with an incredibly high z-index. I'm not sure exactly what restrictions Chrome places on your ability to mess with the current page, but I'm pretty sure you could do that.

Comment: I've heard of someone doing it, I'm a newb at Javascript, so I don't know how i would got about re-setting the CSS through javascript.
**edit:**

alright, I think i figured out how to inject the javascript. Something like this right?
`'function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    document.body.removeChild(script); 
}'`

Comment: You are going to want to use `content_scripts` to inject JavaScript into pages. https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html